# How to spy on useNavigate in react unit testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, navigation, spy

I want to test if useNavigate has been called after clicking on a button and also if it has been called with correct path in my unit test. I try to spy on it, but I keep getting the following error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useNavigate
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
```

Here is the spy in my test that triggers an error:

```
import * as router from "react-router-dom";

jest.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate');
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

```
import * as router from "react-router-dom";

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useNavigate: jest.fn(),
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    router.useNavigate.mockImplementation(
        jest.requireActual('react-router-dom').useNavigate
    );
});

test(...,() => {
    jest.spyOn(router, 'useNavigate');
})
```

I tested this for `react-leaflet` for the `useMap` react hook